# FastAPI Limit external request

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, aiohttp

I have the following code:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
import aiohttp
import asyncio

router = APIRouter()
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(1)

async def request_from_external_api(session):
    async with session.get("some external api endpoint") as response:
        return await response.text()

@router.post("/internal_request_1")
async def internal_request_1():
    async with semaphore:   # limit the number of concurrent requests
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            return await request_from_external_api(session)
        
@router.post("/internal_request_2")
async def internal_request_2():
    async with semaphore:   # limit the number of concurrent requests
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            return await request_from_external_api(session)
```

I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi() running at  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py:420> cb=[set.discard()]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

In my testing file I am doing 2 "simultaneous" request and I want my fastapi app to call `request_from_external_api()` "slowly" 1 by 1.

Comment: The error message suggests that you might have a threading problem, or that there is an error in the initialization of the asyncio loop.  Since you aren't showing us that code, there is little chance of getting help.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- code that we can copy and run locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: If I make this runnable by replacing `router = APIRouter()` with `router = FastAPI()` and then run it (`uvicorn server:router`), it seems to work as expected: each request must wait for pending requests to complete first. If I put an `await asyncio.sleep(5)` in `request_from_external_api`, I get at most one respond every 5 seconds, regardless of how many parallel requests I start.